# Kivy Change Label widget Text from another class

Tags: python, class, widget, label, kivy

I'm having little trouble in updating kivy Label Text runtime,from another class. 
I have tried every possible solution from similar questions but couldn't get result.
In my Application, I am having a main class and another pop-up class. I want to update Text Label of main class widget from pop-up class.

*main.kv file*

```
<JKmain>:
    the_time: _id_lbl_time
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'left'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        BoxLayout:

            orientation: 'vertical'
            id: _tool_box
            size_hint: None,0.75
            width: 300

            Label:
                id: _id_lbl_time
                text: "Total Layers : "

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'right'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        GridLayout:
            rows:2
            ...
            ...
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'horizontal'                           
                Button: 
                    on_release: app.root.current = "main"
                    text: "SELECT"
                    size_hint: 1,0.2
                    background_color: (1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
                    on_release: root.popup_func(self)
                Button: 
                    text: "START"
                    size_hint: 1,0.2
                    background_color: (1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
                    on_release: root.change_text(100)
                Button: 
                    text: "EXIT"
                    size_hint: 1,0.2
                    background_color: (1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
                    on_release: root.exit_app(self)
<ConfirmPopup>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        FileChooserIconView:
            id: filechooser
            filters: ['*.zip']

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2 
            size_hint: 1,0.2
            Button:
                text: 'OK'
                on_release: root.dispatch('on_answer',filechooser.selection)
                size_hint: 1,0.2
            Button:
                text: 'Cancel'
                on_release: root.dispatch('on_answer', 'Cancel')
                size_hint: 1,0.2
```

*ConfirmPopup Class:*

```
class ConfirmPopup(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.register_event_type('on_answer')
        super(ConfirmPopup,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        ...
        ...
        self.total_images=0

    def on_answer(self, filename): 
        ...
        ...
        ...
        if not isdir_empty == "":
            folders = ([name for name in os.listdir(self.project_path)])
            targets = []
            for i in folders:
                if i.endswith('.png'):
                    targets.append(i)
                    self.total_images = len(targets)
        jk = JKMain()
        jk.change_text(self.total_images)
```

*Main Class:*

```
class JKMain(AnchorLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(JKMain, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def change_text(self,layers):
        self.the_time.text = "Total Layers : " + str(layers)
        print "Total Layers = " + str(layers)

    def popup_func(self, instance):

        content = ConfirmPopup()
        content.bind(on_answer=self._on_answer)
        self.popup = Popup(title="Select .zip file",
                            content=content,
                            size_hint=(None, None),
                            size=(500,500),
                            auto_dismiss= False)
        self.popup.open()
    def _on_answer(self, instance, answer):
        self.popup.dismiss()
```

I can update text using *`change_text`* function. From *ConfirmPopup* class , i'm creating instance of *JKMain* and accessing *`change_text`* function to change Label, but its not working

Comment: Your `jk = JKMain()` is creating a new instance of your main class. If your app creates an initial instance of `JKMain`, then you need to reference that initial instance when you try to call the `change_text()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

It is not working because by creating another instance of *JKMain*, now you have two instances of *JKMain* and you are not accessing the first instance which is the root.

## Solution

As a demo that the solution is working, the *self.total_images* is set to *8* in method *on_answer* before invoking method *change_text*.

### kv file

1. No need to pass *self* when calling *root.popup_func*.
2. Pass an instance of the root to method *on_answer*. Please refer to the example and output for details.

### Python script

1. Add a new argument, *JKMain* to the methd *on_answer*.
2. Add a new argument, *obj* to the method *_on_answer*.

### Snippets

#### main.kv

```
<JKmain>:
...
                    on_release: root.popup_func()
...
<ConfirmPopup>:
...
                on_release: root.dispatch('on_answer', filechooser.selection, app.root)
```

#### main.py

```
class ConfirmPopup(BoxLayout):

    ...
    def on_answer(self, filename, JKMain):
        self.total_images = 8
        print("JKMain=", JKMain)
        JKMain.change_text(self.total_images)

class JKMain(AnchorLayout):
    ...
    def popup_func(self):
        ...

    def _on_answer(self, instance, answer, obj):
        self.popup.dismiss()
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup


class ConfirmPopup(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.register_event_type('on_answer')
        super(ConfirmPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.total_images = 0

    def on_answer(self, filename, JKMain):
        self.total_images = 8
        print("JKMain=", JKMain)
        JKMain.change_text(self.total_images)


class JKMain(AnchorLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(JKMain, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def change_text(self, layers):
        self.the_time.text = "Total Layers : " + str(layers)
        print("Total Layers = " + str(layers))

    def popup_func(self):

        content = ConfirmPopup()
        content.bind(on_answer=self._on_answer)
        self.popup = Popup(title="Select .zip file",
                           content=content,
                           size_hint=(None, None),
                           size=(500, 500),
                           auto_dismiss=False)
        self.popup.open()

    def _on_answer(self, instance, answer, obj):
        self.popup.dismiss()


class Main(App):

    def build(self):
        return JKMain()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().run()
```

### main.kv

```
#: kivy 1.10.0

<JKmain>:
    the_time: _id_lbl_time
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'left'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        BoxLayout:

            orientation: 'vertical'
            id: _tool_box
            size_hint: None,0.75
            width: 300

            Label:
                id: _id_lbl_time
                text: "Total Layers : "

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'right'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        GridLayout:
            rows:2
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'horizontal'
                Button:
                    on_release: app.root.current = "main"
                    text: "SELECT"
                    size_hint: 1,0.2
                    background_color: (1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
                    on_release: root.popup_func()
                Button:
                    text: "START"
                    size_hint: 1,0.2
                    background_color: (1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
                    on_release: root.change_text(100)
                Button:
                    text: "EXIT"
                    size_hint: 1,0.2
                    background_color: (1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
                    on_release: root.exit_app(self)

<ConfirmPopup>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        FileChooserIconView:
            id: filechooser
            filters: ['*.zip']

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            size_hint: 1,0.2
            Button:
                text: 'OK'
                on_release: root.dispatch('on_answer', filechooser.selection, app.root)
                size_hint: 1,0.2
            Button:
                text: 'Cancel'
                on_release: root.dispatch('on_answer', 'Cancel')
                size_hint: 1,0.2
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - AppStartup]
[image: Img02 - zip File Selected, OK Button Clicked]
[image: Img03 - Label Total Images Updated]

Comment: Thank you so much again :-).